# Detecting kernel thread on pre-3.0 kernels

Tags: kernel, process, proc

Looking at the proc man page (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) it is possible to detect which processes are kernel threads in `/proc/<pid>/stat` by looking at the `flags` value (`PF_KTHREAD`)

```
flags %u (%lu before Linux 2.6.22)
     (9) The kernel flags word of the process.  For bit
     meanings, see the PF_* defines in the Linux kernel
     source file include/linux/sched.h.  Details depend
     on the kernel version.
```

This process flag (`PF_KTHREAD`) doesn't seem to exist in kernel version 2.6.18 (used in RHEL5), the value is used by a different flag.

Is there another method to determine if a pid is a kernel thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heuristically, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213445/identifying-kernel-threads

`ps` and `top` (from [procps-3.28](http://procps.sourceforge.net/)) use "no command line" as the check, and have no knowledge of `PF_KTHREAD`. That is what triggers them to add ``` [``] ``` to the process name, it's *not* part of the actual process name. Since the command line is under control of the process itself, it's possible that it's been modified.

It depends on how far back (2.4? 2.2?) you need to go. A quick rummage on a few systems indicates no evident common flag (field 9 of `/proc/PID/stat`)

On late 2.6.x you can mostly guess by the the parent PID being 0 for `[kthreadd]`, that often will have PID 2, and all threads will be its children (`init` may have PPID=0 too). Or possibly (early 2.6.x?) a `[kthread]` instead, but not PID 2, but it may only be the parent of most, not all threads.

Another way is to inspect `/proc/PID/maps` (user space memory map), for a kernel thread this will be empty -- so as long the process flag (in `/proc/PID/stat`) is not `&(PF_EXITING)`, `/proc/PID/maps` being empty is a good indicator. Note you must actually read `maps`, not just `stat()` it, since the size is misreported as 0; and you must also have permission, if you do not it may appear empty without causing an error.

```
for pp in /proc/[0-9]*; do 
  if [ -z "$(< $pp/maps)" ]; then echo ${pp##/proc/}; fi; 
done
```

You could add a similar expression to check that `cmdline` is also empty.

Comment: This is perfect.  In the function `isKernelThread(pid)` I just test file length and it seems to be working well. `if not len(readProcFile('/proc/%s/maps' % pid)): return True`

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the `/proc` entry of a kernel thread on a 3.8 series kernel, apparently the `exe` link is empty, the `statm` is full of zeroes, the `status` is missing all the `Vm*` entries and the `maps` is empty too.

Maybe some of these apply to the older kernel in question.